# Forwarding to an GAE appspot account from a URL on names.co.uk

Tags: google-app-engine, url, web

I have a GAE website called http://freeinternetgamereviews.appspot.com.  I also have a URL called www.freeinternetgamereviews.com.  I want people to who go the www.freeinternetgamereviews.com URL to see the former webpages.  I bought my URL through names.co.uk. who allow two forms of forwarding.  Forward to the appspot URL or keep domain name in URL bar.  I don't want to forward as I want people to use www.freeinternetgamereviews.com, and this just changes to the appspot URL.  But second uses a frameset to wrap my URL - over which I have no control - which causes problems for login screens e.g. google (as they won't open in frameset) and also causes problems for google trawling etc and is generally bad.  I also think its ruining my chances of getting google adsense.

Thanks to stackoverflow I got jQuery working in the frameset and can open the login pages in another tab but there must be a better way to forward to the appspot site that the way I am doing?

Thanks

names.co.uk auto generated page:

```
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Free Internet Game Reviews</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Free Games Reviews">
<meta name="description" content="Review site for free internet games">
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
        <frame name="site" src="http://freeinternetgamereviews.appspot.com" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize scrolling="auto">
        <noframes>
            <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <p>Free Internet Game Reviews</p>
            </body>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do either of those. You want to set the DNS for the domain itself to forward to Google, and set up your GAE app to respond to that domain as described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).

Comment: Thanks for this.  This gave me the pointer I needed.  I already had an expired Google Apps account from a previous failed attempt, and after an hour of hunting around whilst following the documentation I eventually found that you can add GAE to the Google Apps dashboard (which then hides at the bottom under "More Controls").  This then allows you to set up a www.mydomain.com web address to point to your appspot.  At that point google walk you through the remaining steps very clearly. This link was also helpful: [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/91077?hl=en)

Comment: The above solution of forwarding the URL via google apps works great EXCEPT after my 1 month free trial I will need to pay $60 a year for the forwarding as I will need to become a paid up user of google apps.  As I don't need/want the other services, this is expensive for some URL forwarding.

Is there any other way (free) way to forward a URL to another URL so when I type www.freeinternetgamereviews.com, it displays the contents of www.freeinternetgamereviews.appspot.com without the use of names.co.uk's frameset.

Thanks